# Mongodb how to access collection which includes special characters i.e. -,?,%?

Tags: mongodb

In mongoDB I am creating collection which contains special names 
for ex-

```
> db.createCollection("collection-demo")
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

but when I am trying to access the collection it gives error

```
> db.collection-demo.find()
2015-07-09T14:44:56.603+0530 ReferenceError: demo is not defined
```

How to access this collection using command line?

Comment: Try `db.getCollection("collection-demo").find()`. And let me search for the duplicate I know I have seen before.

Comment: Use `db['collection-demo'].find()`.

Comment: yes it has solved my problem